# How to subclass or inherit a model from another model using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say my rails models look like this:

```rb
class SalesRelationship < ActiveRecord

end
```

Which is inherited by crossSell like this:

```rb
class crossSell < SalesRelationship 

end
```

How do I show this inheritance relationship in ember-data. What is the best practise for this:

```
App.salesRelationship = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Can I create a subclass called 'crossSell',  like this

```
crossSell = App.salesRelationship({
    productName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

or like this

```
 App.salesRelationship.crossSell  = DS.Model.extend({
    productName: DS.attr('string')
  });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pretty close, you can just extend SalesRelationship.

```
App.CrossSell = App.SalesRelationship.extend({
  productName: DS.attr('string')
})
```

Answer (score 8):

In Ember 2.7 it can be done like this. Assume you have a `Person` class and wish to inherit from it to make an `Employee` for a status field (like hired, retired, fired on-leave etc)

app/models/person.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr(),
  lastName: DS.attr(),
  fullName: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
    return `${this.get('lastName')}, ${this.get('firstName')}`;
});
```

app/models/employee.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

import Person from './person';

export default Person.extend({
  status: DS.attr(),
  statusCode: DS.attr(),
});
```

Comment: How about `import Person from './person';` instead seeing as both models are in the same folder.